# Nhibernate - View extends table, not working

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a table with some fields and properties, and I created a view with the same fields and properties (the only difference is how one field is calculated).
Now, I want to the view will extend the table, the hbm files are the same for both objects (expect the name of course)

The C# code looks something like this:

```
public class Table
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
}

public class View : Table
{
}
```

But when I'm updating the Table object through nhibernate it's also updating the View object, it's making 2 insert operations, and I get an exception:
    Update or insert of view or function '??' failed because it contains a derived or constant field

Can anyone explain\show how I do this inheritance, both in the .hbm and the .cs files

EDIT:

The hbm files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
namespace="???" assembly="???">
<class name="Table" table="Table" lazy="true" dynamic-update="true">
<id name="id" type="long" access="field">
  <column name="ID"/>
  <generator class="native"/>
</id>

<property name="x" type="int" access="field" not-null="false"/>
<property name="y" type="int" access="field" not-null="false"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
namespace="???" assembly="???">
<class name="View" table="View" lazy="true" dynamic-update="true">
<id name="id" type="long" access="field">
  <column name="ID"/>
  <generator class="native"/>
</id>

<property name="x" type="int" access="field" not-null="false"/>
<property name="y" type="int" access="field" not-null="false"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: The content of hbm files would help as well some example of code, which does produce double insert... Because in standard scenario, NHibernate does its job properly

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to this:

> (10) polymorphism (optional, defaults to implicit): Determines whether
>   implicit or explicit query polymorphism is used.
>
> Implicit polymorphism means that instances of the class will be
>   returned by a query that names any superclass or implemented interface
>   or the class and that instances of any subclass of the class will be
>   returned by a query that names the class itself. Explicit polymorphism
>   means that class instances will be returned only be queries that
>   explicitly name that class and that queries that name the class will
>   return only instances of subclasses mapped inside this declaration as
>   a or . For most purposes the default, polymorphism="implicit", is
>   appropriate. Explicit polymorphism is useful when two different
>   classes are mapped to the same table (this allows a "lightweight"
>   class that contains a subset of the table columns).

Take from: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-class